# Windows API: Copying whole directories with overwrite

Tags: windows, winapi

Is there a windows API command that will copy an entire directory, with capability to overwrite an existing directory?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shobjidl_core/nn-shobjidl_core-ifileoperation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Hans Passant said, `IFileOperation interface` has the feature you need.

[**MSDN**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shobjidl_core/nf-shobjidl_core-ifileoperation-copyitem#examples) shows how to copy an object/objects:

*1.Call IFileOperation::CopyItem to declare the source item, destination folder, and destination name.*

*2.Call [IFileOperation::PerformOperations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shobjidl_core/nf-shobjidl_core-ifileoperation-performoperations) to begin the copy operation.*

Also here is a [**sample**](https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-classic-samples/blob/7cbd99ac1d2b4a0beffbaba29ea63d024ceff700/Samples/Win7Samples/winui/shell/appplatform/fileoperations/FileOperationSample.cpp) that can create multiple files under the specified folder path and copy them to the same directory with a new name.